# How to set radio button selected value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

How to set radio button selected value in **javascript**:

HTML Code :

```
<input type="radio" name="RBLExperienceApplicable" class="radio" value="1" > 
<input type="radio" name="RBLExperienceApplicable" class="radio" value="0" >


<input type="radio" name="RBLExperienceApplicable2" class="radio" value="1" > 
<input type="radio" name="RBLExperienceApplicable2" class="radio" value="0" >
```

ASPX Code

```
     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBLExperienceApplicable" runat="server" class="radio"    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" EnableViewState="false">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Yes &nbsp;&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>

     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBLExperienceApplicable2" runat="server" class="radio"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" EnableViewState="false">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Yes &nbsp;&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

// Some Code Fetch from db 
// Based on db value script block will execute

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        RadionButtonSelectedValueSet('1');
 </script>
```

Script Block :

```
function RadionButtonSelectedValueSet(SelectdValue) {
    $('#RBLExperienceApplicable').val(SelectdValue);
        //$("input[name='RBLExperienceApplicable']:checked").val(SelectdValue);
}
```

Comment: can you share the generated html instead of ASP code

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try

```
function RadionButtonSelectedValueSet(name, SelectdValue) {
    $('input[name="' + name+ '"][value="' + SelectdValue + '"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

also call the method on dom ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    RadionButtonSelectedValueSet('RBLExperienceApplicable', '1');
})
</script>
```

Comment: @Sam can you share the generated html... is there a name attribute for the radios

Comment: @Sam can you share the generated html instead of asp code from the browser view source

Comment: Thanks..Works fine.. But above script problem with some brwser.. Little bit modification in code such as :  '$('input[name="' + name + '"][value="' + SelectdValue + '"]').attr('checked', true);'

Comment: @Sam don't use .attr() to set the checked value if you are using jQuery > 1.6, see [prop vs attr](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Comment: @Arul prop not worked in myside.. I have use jquery 1.3.6 only.. Shall i proceed with same..

Comment: Tried many codes that didn't suit my needs, just want to say this is the exact code I've been looking for! Thanks @Arun P Johny

Answer (score 33):

You can do more elegantly.

```
function RadionButtonSelectedValueSet(name, SelectedValue) {
    $('input[name="' + name+ '"]').val([SelectedValue]);
}
```

Comment: Nice. This `val([...])` syntax also works for other inputs, including `<textarea>` and `<select>`. Like I can get all visible inputs using `var inputs = $("form :input:visible[type!=button]")`, then get all their values using `var values = {}; inputs.serializeArray().map( function(x){values[x.name] = x.value} )` and some time later restore all using `inputs.map( function(){var value = values[this.name]; if(value) $(this).val([value])} )`.

Comment: Its important to call `val([SelectedValue])`, and not `val(SelectedValue)`. The second one will set the value attribute to the same value on all the inputs.

Comment: So is this seeking out the radio button with the correct selected value that is passed in and checking it?

Comment: For those wondering if this works everywhere, or is just a hack, here are the docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value which clearly explain that using an array will set the appropriate elements with matching values to selected/checked. Therefore you can also use this to select multiple checkboxes or options in a multi-select.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this also

```
function SetRadiobuttonValue(selectedValue)
{
  $(':radio[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Below script works fine in all browser:

```
function RadionButtonSelectedValueSet(name, SelectdValue) {
     $('input[name="' + name + '"][value="' + SelectdValue + '"]').attr('checked',true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="RBLExperienceApplicable"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Thanks dude...

Answer (score 1):

If the selection changes, make sure to clear the other checks first. al la...

```js
$('input[name="' + value.id + '"]').attr('checked', false);
$('input[name="' + value.id + '"][value="' + thing[value.prop] + '"]').attr('checked',  true);
```

Answer (score 0):

for multiple dropdowns

```
$('[id^=RBLExperienceApplicable][value='+ SelectedVAlue +']').attr("checked","checked");
```

here `RBLExperienceApplicable` is the matching part of the radio button groups input tag ids.
and `[id^=RBLExperienceApplicable]` matches all the radio button whose id start with `RBLExperienceApplicable`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="radio" name="RBLExperienceApplicable" class="radio" value="1" checked > 
 //       For Example it is checked
 <input type="radio" name="RBLExperienceApplicable" class="radio" value="0" >


<input type="radio" name="RBLExperienceApplicable2" class="radio" value="1" > 
<input type="radio" name="RBLExperienceApplicable2" class="radio" value="0" >


      $( "input[type='radio']" ).change(function() //on change radio buttons
   {


    alert('Test');
   if($('input[name=RBLExperienceApplicable]:checked').val() != '') //Testing value
 {

$('input[name=RBLExperienceApplicable]:checked').val('Your value Without Quotes');

}
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6d6FJ/1/
    [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6d6FJ/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblRequestType">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="value1">Value1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Value2">Value2</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

You can set checked like this.

```
var radio0 = $("#rblRequestType_0");
var radio1 = $("#rblRequestType_1");

radio0.checked = true;
radio1.checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean approach I find is by giving an `ID` for each radio button and then setting it by using the following statement:

```
document.getElementById('publicedit').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using the id of the element

example

```
<label><input type="radio" name="travel_mode"  value="Flight" id="Flight"> Flight </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="travel_mode"  value="Train" id="Train"> Train </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="travel_mode"  value="Bus" id="Bus"> Bus </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="travel_mode"  value="Road" id="Road"> Other </label>
```

js:

```
$('#' + selected).prop('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only syntax that worked for me

```
$('input[name="assReq"][value="' + obj["AssociationReq"] + '"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("TestToggleRadioButtonList").rows[0].cells[0].childNodes[0].checked = true;
```

where `TestToggleRadioButtonList` is the id of the `RadioButtonList`.